# How to encode/decode JPG file to int sequence?

Tags: shell-script, images, conversion

I want to convert my JPG files to `int` sequences and then reconvert to get the images again.

My `script.sh` is like this:

```
FILE=$(cat $2)
TOTAL=$(echo ${#FILE} - 1 | bc);
for j in $(seq 0 $TOTAL)
do
    printf "%d " "'${FILE:j:1}" >> sai.out
done
```

It's apparently working fine. So `sai.out` receives something like `32767 32767 32767 32767 16 74 70 73 70 1 1 1 1 32767 32767 67 8 ...`.

With the same code but entering a text file the decodification is easy by ASCII table and printing `%c`.

The problem is: how can I get the image file again starting from my `sai.out` file?

Comment: Which shell are you using? This isn't going to work at all in most of them.

Comment: bash 4.3.11(1). It is working just for text files.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
od -An -vtu1 < file > file.encoded
```

Where each and e`v`ery byte of the file is encoded as a `u`nsigned decimal number, with `n`o `A`ddress.

To decode, with some `awk` implementations (the ones like `gawk` or `mawk` where `printf("%c", 0)` works):

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf "%c", $i}' < file.encoded > file
```

A few notes on why your approach can't work:

- shells other than `zsh` can't store arbitrary data (especially the NUL byte) in their variable.
- and command substitution in Bourne-like shells strips trailing newline characters (0xa bytes on most systems)
- you need to quote variables in Bourne-like shells other than `zsh`
- In shells that have the `${var:offset:length}` `ksh93` operator (`ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`), `offset` and `length` are expressed in number of characters, not bytes (UTF-8 however is the only multi-byte character encoding supported by `mksh` and only when the `utf8-mode` option is enabled).
- `printf %d \'x` returns the codepoint number of the character. That's only the byte value in single-byte character sets. Here, you're probably using `bash` and are in a locale using the UTF-8 encoding as [`bash`'s `printf` gives random values for bytes not forming part of valid characters there](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg20400.html).
- text is defined as sequences of text lines, themselves being sequences of non-NUL *characters* (so limited to byte sequences forming valid characters) whose length (in number of *bytes* including the newline character) doesn't exceed `LINE_MAX` (see `getconf LINE_MAX`) and delimited by a newline character. So except for very small jpg files, your `sai.out` would end up not being valid text and you wouldn't have any guarantee that it would be processed OK by text utilities (`od` here only outputs a few numbers per line).

Answer (score 3):

If hex is a valid integer representation, xxd does the work for you:

```
xxd -p image.jpg > image.hex
```

And, to revert to an image:

```
xxd -p -r image.hex > image-copy.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on Arrow's hint. I am not expert in `sed` so I believe in a better solution than that, but works for now.

The strategy was convert my file to hex with `xxd` and then convert the hex to int.

Encode:

```
xxd -p $1 | sed 's/.\{2\}/& /g' | sed 's/[^ ]* */0x&/g' | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%i ",$i); print ""; }' > $2
```

Decode:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%02x ",$i); print ""; }' $IN > $OUT
xxd -p -r $OUT $OUT_IMAGE_NAME.jpg
rm $OUT
```